# How to use commands from a txt file and store Python outputs in a txt file

Tags: python, operating-system, command-line-interface, argparse, sys

[Input file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wa3RT.png)
I am trying do to following thing,
1-) Take shell commands from a txt file
2-) Store outputs of those commands in an another txt file.

But I am not sure how to use those commands and store them.

```
    import os
    def read_file(file_name): #file_name must be a string
        current_dir_path = os.getcwd() #getting current directory path
        reading_file_name = file_name
        reading_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir_path, reading_file_name) #file path to read

        # Open file
        with open(reading_file_path, "r") as f: #"r" for reading
            data = f.readlines()
        for i in range(len(data)):
            data[i] = data[i].replace("\n", "")
        return data
```

This is my function to read given file and return commands as a list of strings. And,

```
    outputs = "?"
    def write_file(file_name): #file_name must be a string
        current_dir_path = os.getcwd()
        writing_file_name = file_name
        writing_file_path = os.path.join(current_dir_path, writing_file_name)

        # Open file and add
        with open(writing_file_path, "w") as f:

            f.write(outputs)
```

There are several functions that I created. Input file contains lines such that,

```
func1 val1 val2 val3
func3 valx valy valz
func2 val
...
```

I couldn't figured out how to use commands I stored in 'data' and put store their outcomes WITHOUT USING LIBRARIES other than python build-in libraries.

`

Comment: If you have shell commands in a text file, you have a shell script. Why not just execute the script with the shell, instead of trying to pull it apart line-by-line in Python?

Comment: can you give more details? is the first text file gonna contain several commands that you want to execute in sequence then store each command output in a new text file?

Comment: @chepner I don't have a shell script. I have py file that contains functions, including read and write functions. But running the file will be made on shell like py file.py That's why I can't use bash.

Comment: @Obaskly  read_file functions stores the commands from the txt file, but I don't know how to execute them. After running each command write_file should store outputs in an another txt file. I don't know if sys.stdout would work for this task.

Comment: "1-) Take shell commands from txt file". Sure sounds like a shell script to me.

Comment: @chepner what I meant was I must not execute it in shell. So I cant use bash etc. Only command I will write in shell would be py file.py

Comment: So what exactly is in the input files? One-line python statements that use the functions from your .py file?

Comment: @tbeni22 yes. As I wrote in the question, statements are such that (func1 etc are names of the functions that are created in py file), func1 val1 val2 val3. I can use os.system(command) but I dont know how to store outcomes with it.

Comment: Please provide a sample of the file you will be reading from. `os.system(command)` runs a shell command, so you aren't being consistent or clear about what your input actually is. The shell is likely writing to standard output, in which case you want to use the `subprocess` module.

Comment: @chepner I added a image of the file.

Comment: That looks arbitrary text that you might *interpret* as the names of functions defined in your code and the arguments. Basically, it's a custom programming language in its own right.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the output of a command using `subprocess`. You can try the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def write_file(command):
    proc = Popen(command, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,
                            stderr=PIPE)
    ret = proc.stdout.readlines()
    output = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in ret]
    result = output[0]
    with open('output.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(result)
        file.close()

#usage example
write_file('echo hi')
#'hi' will be written in output.txt
```

Comment: Gave this error, in write_file
    result = output[0]
IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: replace `command` in `write_file(command)` by your command

Comment: I wrote the list, of commands, should I put it in a loop?

Comment: @Diotima positive

Comment: Sadly, it gave this error now, in list2cmdline for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable